# Reorganise list in list python

Tags: python, list, key

I need to reorganise two lists in lists and find the total of each key value sum.

```
list1 = [[a,b,c],[a,b,c],[a,b,c],[a,b,c],[b,c],[b,c],[a,c],[a,c],[b],[b],[d],[d]] 

list2 = [[3,5,2],[-5,-2,-3],[12,11,8],[-8,-7,-5],[2,3],[-3,-2],[23,21],[-12,-22],[11],[-11],[22],[-21]]
```

list1 is a list of "strings" (the key) (e.g. "d71de5eb-18d9-4e85-9033-01be046f072e")
list2 is just integers (the value)

new lists (what i'm looking for):

```
list1new = [a,b,c,d]
list2new = [13,6,2,1]
```

Comment: Are the list2 elements the sum of the list2 elements with a value that corresponds to the list1 elements?

Comment: correct. The list2new is the sum of the list2 values corrosponding the the list1 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `itertools.chain` :

```
>>> from itertools import chain , groupby
>>> s=[zip(*i) for i in zip(list1,list2)]
>>> [(set(i).pop(),sum(j)) for i,j in [zip(*i) for i in [list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(chain(*s)),lambda x : x[0])]]]
[('a', 13), ('b', 6), ('c', 2), ('d', 1)]
```

or as more pythonic way you can use `collections.defaultdict` :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in zip(chain(*list1),chain(*list2)):
...     d[k].append(v)
... 
>>> [(k,sum(v)) for k,v in d.items()]
[('a', 13), ('c', 2), ('b', 6), ('d', 1)]
```

---

Demo :

First you can `zip` your lists to get the following :

```
>>> zip(list1,list2)

[(['a', 'b', 'c'], [3, 5, 2]), (['a', 'b', 'c'], [-5, -2, -3]), (['a', 'b', 'c'], [12, 11, 8]), (['a', 'b', 'c'], [-8, -7, -5]), (['b', 'c'], [2, 3]), (['b', 'c'], [-3, -2]), (['a', 'c'], [23, 21]), (['a', 'c'], [-12, -22]), (['b'], [11]), (['b'], [-11]), (['d'], [22]), (['d'], [-21])]
```

now you need to zip all the tuples together , so you can do it with `s=[zip(*i) for i in zip(list1,list2)]`:

```
[[('a', 3), ('b', 5), ('c', 2)], [('a', -5), ('b', -2), ('c', -3)], [('a', 12), ('b', 11), ('c', 8)], [('a', -8), ('b', -7), ('c', -5)], [('b', 2), ('c', 3)], [('b', -3), ('c', -2)], [('a', 23), ('c', 21)], [('a', -12), ('c', -22)], [('b', 11)], [('b', -11)], [('d', 22)], [('d', -21)]]
```

then you need to chain all the inner list for sorting and grouping , thus you can use `itertool.chain` :

```
>>> t=sorted(chain(*s))
>>> t
[('a', -12), ('a', -8), ('a', -5), ('a', 3), ('a', 12), ('a', 23), ('b', -11), ('b', -7), ('b', -3), ('b', -2), ('b', 2), ('b', 5), ('b', 11), ('b', 11), ('c', -22), ('c', -5), ('c', -3), ('c', -2), ('c', 2), ('c', 3), ('c', 8), ('c', 21), ('d', -21), ('d', 22)]
```

now with grouping the above list based on first elements of tuples you can get grub the following :

```
>>> [list(g) for _,g in groupby(t,lambda x : x[0])]
[[('a', -12), ('a', -8), ('a', -5), ('a', 3), ('a', 12), ('a', 23)], [('b', -11), ('b', -7), ('b', -3), ('b', -2), ('b', 2), ('b', 5), ('b', 11), ('b', 11)], [('c', -22), ('c', -5), ('c', -3), ('c', -2), ('c', 2), ('c', 3), ('c', 8), ('c', 21)], [('d', -21), ('d', 22)]]
```

then you can zip nested lists of the preceding result :

```
>>> a=[zip(*i) for i in [list(g) for _,g in groupby(t,lambda x : x[0])]]
[[('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), (-12, -8, -5, 3, 12, 23)], [('b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'), (-11, -7, -3, -2, 2, 5, 11, 11)], [('c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'), (-22, -5, -3, -2, 2, 3, 8, 21)], [('d', 'd'), (-21, 22)]]
```

and at last all you need it get the `set` of first index of ziped elements and sum of second  element  :

```
>>> [(set(i),sum(j)) for i,j in a]
[(set(['a']), 13), (set(['b']), 6), (set(['c']), 2), (set(['d']), 1)]
```

use `pop()` for get the element of `set` .

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer! But your method gives:

"Runtime error (ArgumentTypeException): str is not callable"

For: this code:
[list(g) for _,g in groupby(t,lambda x : x[0])]

Comment: @ThomasPerkov you're welcome did you run that first part i wrote ?

Comment: @ThomasPerkov i minimize the code in top level of answer , you need to use it , that work fine ,

Answer (score 0):

You're parallel lists really aren't helping to make this an easy problem.  The trick will be to flatten the lists and zip them up into a dictionary that maps the string to a list of values.  `itertools` and `collections` can help.

```
>>> a, b, c, d = 'abcd'                                                         >>> list1 = [[a,b,c],[a,b,c],[a,b,c],[a,b,c],[b,c],[b,c],[a,c],[a,c],[b],[b],[d],[d]] 
>>> list2 = [[3,5,2],[-5,-2,-3],[12,11,8],[-8,-7,-5],[2,3],[-3,-2],[23,21],[-12,-22],[11],[-11],[22],[-21]] 
>>> import collections
>>> import itertools
>>> elems1 = itertools.chain.from_iterable(list1)
>>> elems2 = itertools.chain.from_iterable(list2)
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for key, value in zip(elems1, elems2):
...     d[key].append(value)
... 
>>> for k, lst in d.items():
...   print k, sum(lst)
... 
a 13
c 2
b 6
d 1
```

Comment: @kojiro -- Oops.  The code works (Oh the joys of multiple assignment).  But yeah, it's a copy/paste error.